# Three.js events effect the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Simple can/can't question.

Can you set click events in the three.js scene to make changes to the DOM?

e.g. An object in the scene is clicked, and a panel outside the scene is made visible?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to attatch click event to the renderer DOM element as you would to any other

```
renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
```

then calculate where the click occured

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

and raycast to determine what object you pointed at

```
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
```

you can see this used in the draggable cube example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes

after you have you object you can do something to any other (acessible) dom element i.e. display object properties/ position etc outside the screen

if you had in mind something like this

```
myObject.addEventListener
```

then, you would have to code in that yourself and it would still have to be done somehow like the example above because the renderer target is essentially a canvas - an image without information about the objects it holds